# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre comer y comerse?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, definiciones, verbos, reflexivos

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el verbo normal *comer* y su forma reflexiva *comerse*? Si los significados son iguales, ¿cuál es la diferencia de connotación? Y, ¿se usa el reflexivo de la misma manera en todos los países, o hay variación regional?

Comment: Hay casos en que su uso es igual y el significado tambien por ejemplo: El va a comer un pollo y el va a comerse un pollo

Comment: El se va a comer un pollo. El va a comer pollo. Pero no: El va a comer un pollo.

Comment: El va a comer de un pollo (uno de esos, de los que dejamos allí)

Comment: @qPCR4vir Cual es el problema de "El va a comer un pollo" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En [`esta página`](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Verbos%20pronominales%20comentados.htm), del señor **Justo Fernández López** dedicada a los verbos pronominales, he encontrado una descripción que me parece apropiada, así que la transcribo aquí:

> comer – comerse
>
> La forma no pronominal *comer* significa "ingerir
> alimento", "deglutir un alimento sólido", "tomar la comida".
>
> La forma
> pronominal *comerse* significa: "omitir alguna frase, sílaba, letra,
> párrafo, etc., cuando se habla o escribe", "gastar, consumir,
> desbaratar la hacienda, el caudal, etc."
>
> En el sentido de "ingerir
> alimento", la oración *ayer comí paella de marisco* representa una acción concreta,
> muy determinada como tal acción, pero el objeto atiende esencialmente
> a la calidad de lo comido, no a su realidad concreta. Para que se
> utilice la forma pronominal *comerse* es necesario que la oración tenga
> objeto directo determinado, porque lo que se enfatiza, lo que adquiere
> un valor especial es la relación entre el sujeto y un objeto
> determinado: *Ayer me comí una paella de marisco*. Esto vale para los
> verbos que significan "ingerir alimentos sólidos o líquidos": almozar,
> cenar, comer, desayunar, engullir, merendar, tomar (beber), tragar,
> fumar y otros.

Comment: "La oración *ayer comí paella de marisco* representa una acción concreta, muy determinada como tal acción, pero el objeto atiende esencialmente a la calidad de lo comido, no a su realidad concreta." No entiendo la diferencia entre "atender a la calidad de lo comido" y "atender a su realidad concreta". Podrías explicar?

Answer (score 1):

Aquí se explica como una decisión que depende del objeto: no se usa comerse cuando no se explicita el objeto o se habla de una categoría o en general; se usa comerse cuando se explicita el objeto y éste está perfectamente perfilado. Con ejercicios:

http://terceragramatica.com/comer-o-comerse/

Comment: FYI - That link redirects to the wordpress login page.

Answer (score 0):

Asi pues es incorrecto, decir "me voy a comer" sin decir que comes,pues no hay objeto  directo determinado, lo correcto es: "VOY A COMER" Se entiende la intecion pues nadie se come a si mismo, pero no por eso deja de ser incorrecto.

Comment: _“Me voy a comer”_ es gramaticalmente correcto pero siguiendo otra regla.  El reflexivo aquí no es _comer/comerse_ sino _ir/irse_.  Si te despides y abandonas el lugar bien puedes decir _“Me voy a comer”_, y si quieres ser específico _“Me voy a comerme un emparedado”_.